# Restart sound engine in Android (4.1)

Tags: audio, htc-desire-s, aokp

I am Running AOKP on my HTC Desire S and it has a weird issue with sound - If I reboot the device with headphones plugged in, the sound (specifically the bass) is OK but if I remove the headphones and if any kind of sound is played through the Phone's speaker (a touch, a keystroke, a song, a notification anything) and then try to plug in the headphones again, the bass cracks. Of course, I have reported the issue to original developer who has ported the build, but for now if I could just restart the sound engine, I may be able to solve it temporarily. Is there any such service that runs or is there any way to do so?

AOKP 4.1 milestone 1

**EDIT**: This is not an answer to my original question (so not putting as an answer) but this kind of solved my problem. Well when you lose bass, just plug the headphones in, call a number (I always call my customer care which is toll free and not human :P) wait for the ring, cut the call and Whoila! The bass is back! :D I know it sounds crazy, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this isn't patronising, but did you go to sound settings and check that the "safe headset volume" button is deselected?

Comment: Yup, I did already. Did not help! :/